# My smax function is not working properly even though execution of nload is right

Tags: gams-math

I can not find the answer by myself and therefore I'm asking you.  I'm trying to modify the input load subject to two different price range. It goes well I receive answers on nload, however when it comes to find the maximum value it doesn't work. I have even replaced smax with an number, but the output answer is being strange...

```
Con3(d,hpd)..                                    ndload(d,hpd) =E= odload(d,hpd)*(1+sum(hpd1,PRICE_EL(hpd,hpd1)*(P_H(hpd1)-PH_OLD)/PH_OLD));


Con4(hpd)$((ord(hpd)>15)and(ord(hpd)<23))..     P_H(hpd) =E= PHP;

Con5(hpd)$((ord(hpd)<16)or(ord(hpd)>22))..      P_H(hpd) =E= PLP;

Con6..                                           E_NEW =E= sum((d,hpd),ndload(d,hpd)) ;;

Con7..                                           LF_NEW =E= sum(d,NDLF(d))/1;

Con8(d)..                                        NDLF(d) =E= sum(hpd,ndload(d,hpd))/(smax(hpd,ndload(d,hpd))*24);
```

Comment: What's the input that produces this output?

Comment: my input data is read from a file, i recieve information regarding the hourliy data (nload) however i can not use smax function to pick out the element with highest value

Comment: `max` and `smax` are "dangerous" functions as they are not differentiable (in most cases). You should only use these if you really know what you are doing. Fortunately in most cases one can reformulate things to avoid them.